# NullPointer exception on managed property (service)

Tags: java, spring

I am facing a null pointer exception on my app , I am annotating Dao with `@Repository` , the servive by `@Service` , controller with `@Controller` and service inside it with `@ManagedProperty`, I am suspecting my application context is not well configured so here there is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xml:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <!-- Enable Spring Annotation Configuration -->

    <context:annotation-config/> 
    <!-- Scan for all of Spring components such as Spring Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.domain.nameOfapp.*" />

    <!-- Necessary to get the entity manager injected into the factory bean -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- Define Hibernate JPA Vendor Adapter -->
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpa-persistence" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.domain.nameOfapp.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Detect @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"  />

</beans>
```

Any help would be great! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your component scan needs to be as below,

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.domain.nameOfapp" />
```

This will scan all the classes under this package including any sub-packages.

Also using `@ManagedProperty`, are you trying to autowire the spring service bean? I believe you should be using `@Autowired`.

Comment: I am autowirning the dao in the service and using @managedProperty to the service at controller level

Comment: isnt `@ManagedProperty` a JSF annotation?  Did it work after you made the above mentioned change? if not, can you try changing the `@ManagedProperty` to `@Autowired` ?

Comment: no still didnt work , and also switching managed property to autowired neither, thanks for your help!